# Rails 3 - Active Admin - flash_notice missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, notice

I've been trying and searching for any solution for days now..

I use the active_admin gem in my rails 3 application but i only get flash notices after login - not after any update/delete/add -action.

Does anyone have a clue what could be the source of this problem? I am kinda new to Rails..

Simon